# Extract every value in a 3D (time, lat, lon) array and create a list or 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, histogram

Forgive me if this is simple but I am new to python. I have daily wind speed data with one data point for every latitude(180) and longitude(360) and time(6624) which is a 3D array with numpy.shape (time, lat, lon). I am trying to extract every wind speed and put it into a new array or list so that I can plot a histogram or a probability density function. Is there a way in python to extract each of these values?

Comment: you mean you need every row the matrix with the lat, long and time to generate the function?

Comment: Yes, there is 6624 days of wind speed data with one value for every lat and lon cell, and the point is to be able to look at a specific cell and extract the 6624 wind speeds to create a histogram if that makes any sense. Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: provide few rows of your 3d array, because slicing will change depending on how the array is shaped

Comment: have you looked [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Here is a sample of the data 
(wind_speedjja[0:1,:,:])
array([[[ 3.84302425,  3.85788465,  3.87297344, ...,  3.79931521,
          3.81356525,  3.82767272],
        [ 2.61478281,  2.61992002,  2.62531614, ...,  2.6005969 ,
          2.60529995,  2.60992217],
        ..., 
        [ 7.33358574,  7.19630527,  7.33323956, ...,  7.54264212,
          7.53644514,  7.49996758],
        [ 7.13919353,  7.22122383,  7.55467606, ...,  6.97763348,
          7.11504269,  7.16432858]]], dtype=float32)

Comment: You must precise which histogram you want wind=f(time) at any point ? wind_mean/xy=f(time) ?    wind_mean/t = f(x,y) ?  all of them ?

Answer (score 1):

so if you do `wind_speedjja.shape` you get `(6624, 180, 360)`?

This is not an efficient answer, more written for being illustrative with a nested loop.

```
all_wsp = np.array([])
mtx = wind_speed.shape
for idx_lat in range(mtx[1]):
    for idx_long in range(mtx[2]):
        lat_long_wsp = wind_speed[:, idx_lat, idx_long]
        # do a plot on lat_long_wsp, or your histogram
        all_wsp = np.concatenate((all_wsp, lat_long_wsp))
        # all_wsp will be all single values in a flattened array
```

If you are just after the flattened array, do `flat_wsp = windspeed.flatten()`.

Comment: Yes, that is the shape of wind_speedjja.

Comment: That code looks like it might work. I am testing it now, however, with this many data points, it is taking a long time. I will update once I get get a result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your data are huge, so you must first have global approach.

As a toy example :

```
from pylab import *

wind = rand(662,18,36)
means = wind.mean(axis=0)
subplot(121)
hist(means.ravel(),100)  
subplot(122)
imshow(means)
colorbar()
show()
```

[image]

Then you can decide which area  you will refine.